# Convert search in list using simple for loop to stream approach

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to get an integer value out of list of objects (Labels) and one of the fields inside this object is integer which I would like to retrieve.

I was able to do it using simple foreach loop and I wonder how it can be done using java 8 Stream approach.

```
 public int getLabelIdByLabelName(String labelName) throws ApiException {
        List<Labels> labelsList = labelsAPI.listAllLabels();
        for(Labels labels : labelsList){
            if(labels.getName().equals(labelName)){
                return labels.getId();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried before? How didn't that work out and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent stream can be :

```
public int getLabelIdByLabelName(String labelName) throws ApiException {
    return labelsAPI.listAllLabels().stream()
        .filter(label -> label.getName().equals(labelName))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Labels::getId)
        .orElse(0);
}
```